# Modifying gcloud VM service account permissions without stopping the VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, gcloud

I'm trying to upload a file from a Google Cloud VM into a cloud storage bucket.

Expectedly it fails because the service account associated with the VM doesn't have permissions:

```
$ gsutil cp file.png gs://bucket/
Copying file://file.png [Content-Type=image/png]...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission
```

From what I understand there are two ways to fix this:

- modify the scopes from the VM web admin panel
- change the permissions of the bucket and add the service account with write access (I'd prefer this because the other option seems to give access to all buckets in the same project)

However, it seems that both solutions require the VM to be stopped, which is problematic as it is a production server.

Is there any way to fix this without stopping the VM?

Comment: Adding the service account to the bucket (as a resource) does not require shutting down or rebooting the VM. Changing the VM scopes does require shutting down the VM.

Comment: @JohnHanley interesting, I tried that, added all kinds of write permissions, but still got this error... I may have missed something, not sure. Anyways I ended up stopping the VM and modifying the scopes, it's working fine now.

Comment: Compute Engine VM scopes limit permissions granted to the service account. If you have deselected a scope for Cloud Storage, then yes, you will need to shut down the VM to change the scope. Note that scopes do not grant permission to a service account, scopes limit already assigned permissions. VM Scopes are a legacy mechanism that existed before IAM and service accounts were implemented. My advice is to enable all scopes for the VM and then limit the roles assigned to the service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods of controlling permissions granted to a Compute Engine VM.

1. Access Scopes
2. Service Account assigned to the instance.

Both of these methods work together. The total permissions ***available*** to a Compute Engine instance is controlled by the service account. Access Scopes then limit the permissions ***assigned*** to the VM.

You must shutdown a VM to change the Access Scopes. Changing the service account roles does not require rebooting the VM.

For this question regarding Cloud Storage Access:

If the service account has a Cloud Storage role granting access to cloud storage but the Access Scope for Storage is set to None, then the VM will not have access to Cloud Storage even though the service account has the required role. In this case you must shutdown the VM to change the Access Scope to enable access to Cloud Storage.

If the VM Access Scope has Storage enabled, but the service account does not have a Cloud Storage role, the VM will not be able to access Cloud Storage. In this case, adding a Cloud Storage role to the service account will grant access to Cloud Storage without requiring a VM reboot.

Access Scopes (OAuth Scopes) are a legacy mechanism that existed prior to Google Cloud IAM. Given that you are using this VM in a production environment and shutting down the instance is not desired, I recommend the following:

- Set the VM Access Scopes to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs".
- Create a new service account with the required roles and assign that service account to the Compute Engine VM instance.

Comment: Does this solution avoid shutting down the VM? First bullet point says to set the VM Access Scopes, but can this be done without shutting down the VM?

Comment: @MichaelNelson To edit the Virtual machine access scopes requires shutting down the VM. Editing the IAM roles assigned to a service account does not require shutting down the VM.

Comment: Is the TL;DR; version of your answer `not possible without shutdown`, give that access scopes for an instance are not modifiable without shutting down it down?

Comment: @Samveen -  To change (edit) a VM's access scopes requires shutting down the instance.